# Actions.dragAndDropBy is not working as expected

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote following piece of code to move a draggable object on
 https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

```
    driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/draggable/");
    WebElement eleFrame=driver.findElement(By.className("demo-frame"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(eleFrame);
    WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='draggable']"));
    Actions move=new Actions(driver);
    move.dragAndDropBy(ele, 180, 300).release().build().perform();
```

This code does not move the object.

when i tried

```
move.clickAndHold(ele).moveByOffset(300, 100).release().build().perform();
```

it is working fine.I read the documnets it is saying dragAndropBy have internally same functionality as clickAndHold and then moving by some offset.

I have tested it before for both vertical/horizontal slider and it used to work fine.

Please suggest what is the problem with dragAndDropBy code. or some other functionality is actually expected out of it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you remove `release()` method from `dragAndDropBy` method? I read in docs that dragAndDropBy already invokes `release()` internally

Comment: yes i tried with both but that is not working.at first i was not using release because i knew it invokes those steps internally.Then i added to test that in case it works or not

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's pretty weird that `move.clickAndHold(ele).moveByOffset(300, 100).release().build().perform();` is working for you... I've tried them both and they throw the same exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: moveto did not match a known command
```

However, there are [open bugs in Selelnium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2285) and in [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/159) on this issue.

BTW, the only difference between the two is that you don't have the `ButtonReleaseAction` in your custom action.

Comment: i am not getting exception in any of the cases.its just that   (move.dragAndDropBy) is not able to move the element and the second one is able to move the slider

Comment: Yes, I understood that from the question ;) You asked for suggestions on problems with `dragAndDropBy`  code and that's what I answered about...

Answer (score 0):

You can use dragAndDrop() method.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.dragAndDrop(sourceElement, destinationElement).build().perform();
```

Refere tutorial http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/drag-and-drop-using-webdriver-action-class

Comment: i want to move the element by some offset.I don't have defined destinationElement

Answer (score 0):

No need to release() When "dragAndDropBy" is used. 
Try this: 
**move.dragAndDropBy(ele, 180, 300).build().perform();**

Comment: First i tried without release it was not working.Then i tried with release still it was not working

Comment: Could you provide more details like browser version and webdriver version

Comment: chromedriver 2.25 browser version chrome- 54.0

Comment: Change xPath to: "//*[@id='draggable']/p"

Comment: Change xPath to: "//*[@id='draggable']/p" and execute. Make sure to remove release().

Comment: Actually i tried one more thing when i have reduced the offset like(50,60) it is working but for offset like(180,200) its not working.But clickAndHold(ele).moveByOffset works for that offset also

Answer (score 0):

**Multiple Controls Drag and Drop to the Same Destination.**

```
WebElement element_1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-lobid='12']"));      //source element 1

WebElement element_2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-lobid='21']"));     //source element 2

WebElement destination = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='lobModalPopUp']/div"));  //destination path

int[] array_source = new int[]{12,21};  // create fixed array for id number of source element 1 and 2

for(int i = 0; i<array_source.length; i++)  //Passing id number of source element 1 and 2 inside the for loop.
{
        WebElement all_source_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-lobid='"+arraylobs[i]+"']"));  // getting all source element with the help of fixed array.

        Actions drag = new Actions(driver);
        drag.clickAndHold(all_source_element).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(3500);
        drag.clickAndHold().moveToElement(destination).release(destination).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(3500);
}
```

Comment: Please Mark this answer as `Accepted`, if it's resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/draggable/");
    driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    WebElement dragMe = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-draggable-handle"));
    new Actions(driver).dragAndDropBy(dragMe, dragMe.getLocation().getX()+100, dragMe.getLocation().getY()+100).perform();
```

> This is how to use the dragAndDropBy(WebElement source, int xOffset, int yOffset) method provided in Actions class to perform drag and drop operations.

- WebElement source: web-element that you want to drag around.
- int xOffset and int yOffset are future x-axis and y-axis coordinate positions. Basically, the code gets the current x-axis and y-axis coordinate positions and adds int number to move the draggable element.

Please make sure to set up your driver properly before using this block of code.